# Capturing WindowsError in template

Tags: python, django

I'm coding on a Windows machine but I'm running my production site on Linux.

When trying to reach a page on my development machine using a database copied from the production system, I get errors while trying to list files if these files don't exist locally. 
This is as expected, since I just copied the DB and not the files. I don't want/need the files, but I don't want following error either:

> WindowsError at /126/documents/ [Error 3] The system cannot find the
>   path specified:
>   u'C:\mysite\media\documents\2016\07\26\myfile.docx'

Instead of throwing the error, I'd prefer to handle this in my template, something like:

```
{% if doc.data %}{{ doc.data.size | filesizeformat }}{% else %}File not found{% endif %}
```

However that doesn't work. `doc.data` *does* exist, since the DB knows a value for this file location. But the file isn't available on the disk.

Any way to catch this properly, preferably in the template?

My model:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    data = models.FileField(upload_to="documents/%Y/%m/%d")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best answer, but a workaround can be implemented as follows in `views.py` (not in the template):

```
documents = Document.objects.all()

if documents:
    exclude_list = []
    for doc in documents:
        try:
            local_file = doc.data.file
        except IOError:
            exclude_list.append(doc.id)
    documents = documents.exclude(id__in=exclude_list)

context_dict['documents'] = documents
```

This way the document is not displayed in the template if there is no valid local file found.